# Keras error Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 5, 95)

Tags: keras

I'm trying to create a simple RNN using keras but I'm getting this error.
Input is a stream of letters represented by binary classes. The shape is (10, 5, 95). 10 batches, 5 letters at a time, 95 characters in total.

I'm guessing it has something to do with incorrect input fed back as input but I'm not sure how to handle it.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "07_rnn.py", line 90, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=3, batch_size=BATCHSIZE)
  File "/home/dmabelin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 965, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/dmabelin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1593, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/dmabelin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1430, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/dmabelin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 110, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 5, 95)
```

Code

```python
import numpy as np
import glob
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
CHARMAP = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+`~[]\{}|;':\",./<>?"

SEQLEN = 5
BATCHSIZE = 10
ALPHASIZE = len(CHARMAP)
INTERNALSIZE = 128
FILES = "shakespeare/*.txt"
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001


## Data related stuff

def char_to_value(char):
    idx = CHARMAP.find(char)
    if idx >= 0:
        return idx
    else:
        return 0

def char_to_class_map(char):
    value = char_to_value(char)
    return to_categorical(value,ALPHASIZE)

def value_to_char(value):
    return CHARMAP[value]

# iterate every single file
def get_file_data(pattern, index):
    paths = glob.glob(pattern)
    length = len(paths)

    if index < length:
        data = []
        with open(paths[index], "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                line_values = [char_to_class_map(l) for l in line]
                data = data + list(line_values)
        return data
    else:
        return None

# get batch data in file
def build_line_data(file_data, seqlen, batch_index, batch_count):
    length = len(file_data)
    start = batch_index * batch_count
    end = start+seqlen
    x = []
    y = []
    while end+1 <= length and len(x) < batch_count:
        x_line = file_data[start:end]
        y_line = file_data[start+1:end+1]
        x.append(x_line)
        y.append(y_line)
        start = start + 1
        end = start + seqlen
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return x,y


def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(INTERNALSIZE,input_shape=(SEQLEN, ALPHASIZE)))
    model.add(Dense(ALPHASIZE))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    #adam optimizer
    optimizer = Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

print('before create_model')
model = create_model()
print('after create_model')
for i in range(1):
    print('before get file data')
    file_data = get_file_data(FILES, i)
    print('after get file data')
    idx = 0
    while True:
        print('before build line data')
        x,y = build_line_data(file_data, SEQLEN, idx ,BATCHSIZE)
        print('after build line data')
        print('before fit')
        model.fit(x, y, epochs=3, batch_size=BATCHSIZE)
        print('after fit')
        idx = idx + 1
        if 0 == len(x):
            break
        if idx > 10:
            break
```

github link: https://github.com/djaney/ml-studies/blob/master/07_rnn.py

Edit:
return_sequences=True in LSTM fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to predict? If it is a sequences-to-sequence model than `return_sequences=true` is the right way to go.
The reason for the error is that your target was 3 dimensional `(batchsize,sequence_length,features)` and the LSTM layer only outputs `(batchsize,features)` for the last time step of the sequence if `return_sequences=false`.
So depending on your application you have to change the shape of your targets or set `return_sequences=true` as you already did.